# Most durable paint type for baseboards and trim

Tags: paint

I want to paint (*by brush*) some stair and baseboard trim in my basement.

I’m looking for the most durable type of paint, (*not brand recommendations*). It seems the higher the sheen the more durable. I would like something that is scuff resistant, can be washed, and  applied easily.

Also, can one apply a polyurethane coat over paint for more protection? Are paints available that contain polyurethane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latex door & trim paints I use are "scuff resistant, can be washed, and applied easily".

The issue with trim damage is abrasion before curing.  Curing takes 30 days. "Dry" is not the same as cured.

The next step up is a furniture grade melamine paint.

Polyurethane coating is good if there is regular water exposure, e.g. pooling bathroom water, window condensation. Otherwise, durable latex paints are excellent provided the right variant is chosen for the application.

Answer (score 1):

"Two Pack" or "2K" is the hardest paint. It is polyurethane based.

It has a volatile organinc solvent, and outgasses during curing so use lots of ventilation, the stuff is nasty, positive pressure respirators are used in industrial applications.

Clear polyurethane (two part or one part) can be used over existing paint to protect it.